# Teams Bot - The tenant admin disabled this bot, error when getTeamsDetails

Tags: typescript, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

As mentioned in the title, I'm getting "Tenant admin disabled this bot" as an exception error and also in the bot registration "msteams" channel warning errors.

I'm able to chat with a bot but it fails in action task in message extension which is trying to get Team details using `TeamsInfo.getMembers(context)` or `TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(context)`. I deployed the same in another tenant in West US and it's working as expected without issues.

Sideloading is enabled in the Teams admin center.

Any help?

Comment: Could you please check if you have allowed tenant app in teams admin center? It takes sometime to reflect sideloading in teams

Comment: Thanks! its resolved now. Sideloading has been applied through a new setup policy in the admin center but it was failing when new users were added. The support team was able to fix that issue, and after a few hours, we were able to use the bot.